# Windows 7 Boot Loop: Startup Repair fails, sfc /scannow complains repair pending

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi, system-restore, windows-7-backup

I have a Win7-64 machine (using EFI boot) that was working OK, but has developed a boot loop.  It reboots, enters Startup Repair, and fails with ExternalMedia, CorruptVolume.

I booted the Win7 install disk (straight-from-Microsoft Win7 Ultimate, using UEFI boot) and entered Repair.  `chkdsk -v -f c:` finds no errors, but `sfc /scannow` refuses to run, saying that there's a repair pending.

I tried many of the `dism` recipes to rollback pending updates, etc., and the `bcdboot` and `bootrec` recipes for fixing the boot record.  No change.

The disk itself appears to be OK: I made a clone using a disk-to-disk docking station, and the clone behaves exactly the same way as the original disk.

The user data appears to be OK, so I could just do a fresh install, install all the programs, and then copy the user data over, but that's a LOT of work.  Is there any way to:

1. Fix the boot loop enough that I can make an up-to-date system recovery image before a fresh install?
2. Copy programs and user data (for several different users) from the broken-boot disk into a fresh install, without having to fix endless permissions problems?

Comment: You say that you have a W7 machine with EFI boot, single or multi boot? How did it develop that loop? No W7 machine can "develop" itself ;) There was an update, you made some changes or some new software made changes to system?

Comment: Single boot, the W7 install process picked EFI (I'm not very familiar with that boot method, although I know my Macs use it.  But this is a standard Mini-ITX PC, Gigabyte F2A88X-Wifi, AMD A10-7850K CPU.  It's a few years old and has been reasonably reliable.)  I found the boot loop when I woke up one morning...I think it probably installed an update overnight which failed.  I set the machine to only install updates when I explicitly say so, but I think it still does some installs or system changes or something on its own.  I don't trust M$!

Comment: pending reboot means there is a pending.xml in winsxs. run **DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions** from cmd of repair options to revert all pending actions. now try to run sfc

Comment: That's one of the things I tried...I also looked in `winsxs` directly.  There are ~18700 directories (apparently info about previously-applied updates?) and files `Starter.xml` and `Ultimate.xml`, but no directory or file named `pending.xml`.

Comment: Wait, sorry, `Starter.xml` and `Ultimate.xml` are in `C:\Windows`.  In `winsxs`, there was `reboot.xml`.  I renamed it and restarted, but it didn't make any difference.  The Startup Repair process fails with EventName `StartupRepairOffline`, Signature01 `6.1.7600.16385`, Signature05 `ExternalMedia`, Signature06 `15`, Signature07 `CorruptVolume`

Comment: In `winsxs`, there is a `Temp` directory containing a directory, `PendingRenames`.  However, autocomplete for `dir` completes to `PendingDeletes` (not visible in the directory list).  `PendingDeletes` contains 2 files, while `PendingRenames` contains 9520.  (Coincidentally, that's near half of the number of directories in `winsxs`.)  I renamed `Temp` to `Temp-broken` and created a new `Temp`, but `sfc` still won't run.  It seems like there's maybe a filesystem loop or something (because of the `PendingRenames` and `PendingDeletes` weirdness) but `chkdsk` says everything is OK.

Comment: Made some progress by deleting the `Temp-broken` directory, `chkdsk`, and now `sfc /offbootdir=C:\ /offwindir=C:\windows /scannow` is running. [...] `sfc` found no errors, but the system still runs Startup Repair on reboot, and it still fails.

Comment: There was a `pending.xml` in `X:\windows\winsxs`...I assumed `X:` was a temporary mount of the filesystem for the Win7 installation CD, but maybe it's a magic filesystem based on `C:`?

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot of things, mostly focusing on the boot record, but without any luck.  I think many of the scripts and guides out there may be designed for MBR disks, but my system is using EFI, so it doesn't have, for example, `C:\boot\BCD` to delete and re-create.  (I also tried EasyRecovery Essentials from NeoSmart, which is a FreeBSD-based automatic recovery boot disk.  This booted properly, but the proprietary program that is supposed to find & fix things crashed with a SEGV.  I will update this answer if NeoSmart support responds and provides help, but at the moment, I can't say anything good about this $19.75 "guaranteed fix."  Update: tech support responded and provided a beta copy of their new version.  It didn't crash, but it also didn't fix the disk (I had kept a clone of the broken disk, and it didn't fix it.)  So: thumbs down on NeoSmart Easy Recovery.)

The thing that *did* help, though, was [a post on answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/total-identified-windows-installations-0/52359f87-de4a-41dc-b0c3-cc275e1d9fbf):

> In my case, I'e booted the installation-DVD, Repair, Advances, Command
>   Prompt.
>
> Then I navigated to C:\Windows\System32\config.
>
> There I've renamed ...
>
> DEFAULT SAM SECURITY SOFTWARE SYSTEM
>
> to *.old and copied the registry-hives from
>   C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack to C:\Windows\System32\config.
>
> After this, I was able to boot, without loced drive, without
>   Critical_Process_dies, etc.

After renaming and copying the registry backups as described, I was able to boot my system without a System Repair loop, and I am creating a system image to reconfigure a fresh install.

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing the solution. next time notify me with @ my username in the comments, I haven't see that you replied to me.

Comment: what if after copying those 5 files from `config\RegBack` to `config` it gives the same error? @magicandre1981

Comment: @golimar this is not my solution, so I have no idea. Add a bounty to the question, telling that the solution doesn't work and you need a 2nd answer.